# How to force price resolver when programmatically adding a new item to an existing cart?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have built in my drupal 8 custom module a custom Commerce addtocart form, which allows me to have multiple instances of the form on one page, using the cartManager->addEntity() method described in various websites such as https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-add-a-product-programmatically-to-drupal-commerce-cart

I also have a price resolver which manages multiple currencies based on geoip, as explained here https://www.drupaldump.com/drupal-8-commerce-2x-multi-currency-how
I have custom fields with prices in different currencies for each product variation.

It works perfectly fine when someone adds a product for the first time. The right currency is picked based on the user IP.
Unfortunately (and I think this is recent as I think I did not have this problem in 2019), when I add another product (with a different product id), the price resolver is not triggered and as a result I get the following error:

> Drupal\commerce_price\Exception\CurrencyMismatchException: The provided prices have mismatched currencies: 99 CHF, 149 USD. in Drupal\commerce_price\Price->assertSameCurrency() (line 316 of /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/www/site/web/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/price/src/Price.php).

I tried to empty the cart and adding again the items already in the cart plus the new one but the problem remains. I did not manage to delete completely the cart/order to start from scratch (and I suspect the problem would remain for the second item).

**Hence my question: is there a way to force the pricing resolver to be triggered for cart additions with the addEntity method? If not, how should I change my add to cart form?**

My custom add to cart form:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->set('productid',$this->formId);
    $form['sample'.$this->formId] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('ADD TO CART'),
      '#submit' => array('::newSubmissionHandler')
    );
            return $form;

    }
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    }

  public function newSubmissionHandler(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $productId = $form_state->get('productid');
   $this->addtocart($productId);
  }

    public function addtocart($productId){
      $productObj = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product::load($productId);

      $product_variation_id = $productObj->get('variations')
        ->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
      $storeId = $productObj->get('stores')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
      $variationobj = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')
        ->load($product_variation_id);
      $store = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('commerce_store')
        ->load($storeId);

      $cart = $this->cartProvider->getCart('default', $store);

      if (!$cart) {
        $cart = $this->cartProvider->createCart('default', $store);

      }

      $cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');

      $line_item = $cart_manager->addEntity($cart, $variationobj);

      return;
    }
}
```

My price resolver function:

```
public function resolve(PurchasableEntityInterface $entity, $quantity, \Drupal\commerce\Context $context) {
    $userIp = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
    $usercountrycode = $this->myservices->getCountryCode($userIp);


    switch ($usercountrycode) {
      case 'BE':
       $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_eur')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'CA':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_cad')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'CH':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_chf')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'JP':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_jpy')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'KR':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_krw')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'SG':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_sgd')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'GB':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_gbp')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'IN':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_inr')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      case 'CN':
        $localprice = $entity->get('field_price_cny')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
      default:
        $localprice = $entity->get('price')->first()->toPrice();
        break;
    }
    return new Price($localprice->getNumber(), $localprice->getCurrencyCode());
  }
```

My resolver service declaration:

```
  modulename.custom_price_resolver:
    class: Drupal\modulename\Resolvers\CustomPriceResolver
    arguments: ['@modulename.myservices','@request_stack']
    tags:
      - { name: commerce_price.price_resolver, priority: 600}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.